# What kind of connector is this? Some kind of Molex?

Tags: power-supply, identification, connector

[image]

Best I can tell with the calipers, the pitch is 8.50 mm.

It's for a 12 V power supply.

Comment: Or part numbers for the power supply and the equipment it plugs into?

Comment: Annoyingly the part numbers have been scratched off for some reason.

Comment: @SurikTorosyan to prevent repair?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to be a Molex 0003121036:
https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/003121036_sd.pdf

Comment: TE also makes compatible connectors, I believe.